# sharepoint server cant deploy solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, solution-deployment

I was able to deploy same solution last week, nothing changed and the error message also not about project but server.. This is the error message I see in
solution management page;

Screenshot:
[image]

Any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Is the Default IIS site stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the "MaliyeCore.dll" is being used by a process while you deploying the solution.

1st you can use the Process explorer and check which porcess locked this dll, you can stop the process then redeploy the solution.

Many times SharePoint time service locked the dll, In that case Recycle the `SharePoint timer service` after that re deploy the solution.